# Intent not getting posted sometimes

Tags: android, android-intent

In Android, I am posting an intent to start an activity when a list item is clicked.
99% of the time, that activity is started.
But sometimes, when I click the list item, I get a blank screen.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

mdv , it seems 1% times you launched the app before data is loaded OR no data to initiate the new activity. Is data loading asynchronous?